# how to do windows driver signing ?

Tags: c#, c, driver

I have developed windows kernel driver using vs 2015.
But I can't install this in 64bit os.
To install in 64bit, I must do sign driver like product mode for public release.
To generate product sign, i have to know product certificate.
But i can't get this product certificate from my crt file.
How can i do product mode sign. Look at below image.[image]

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/driver-signing) is MS doc about driver signing.

Comment: Do you have a proper certificate? The question suggests you don't know how signing works, which probably also means you don't have a certificate that Windows will trust.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to first get EV Code signing Certificate for EV signing.
2. Create cab file of your driver and sign that cab file.
3. Now upload this EV signed cab file to [sys dev portal](https://sysdev.microsoft.com) for attestation signing or what ever signing type your product need.

You can follow driver signing policy given in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-)

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel driver is targeting Windows 10 64 bit, build 1607 then you'll need to sign your sys and the cat file with an EV code signing certificate. Then you'll need to submit them to the Windows Sys Dev Portal, Microsoft will attest them. Please refer to this [attestation-signing-a-kernel-driver-for-public-release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/attestation-signing-a-kernel-driver-for-public-release?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If your kernel driver has been developed for Windows 8.1, 8 or 7, 64 bit then you'll just need to sign your sys and cat files with an EV code signing certificate. Please refer to this [blog](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/), David has covered almost every topic related to driver signing.